# Is there any other more efficient approach for getting the possible moves in a Matrix and for iterating over them?

Tags: java

I am creating an algorithm in Java for playing the isolation game (1vs1) board game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(board_game)
Basically my problem concerns moving a pawn following several rules (later specified). I have created this solution (it works) to **get the moves(only the ones that are possible) of the pawn and to iterate over them**  to create news states of the problem and ***I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way to solve this.*** Basically, the roles of the movements are:

1. The pawn can move in the 8 possibles directions(up, down, left, right, diagonals).
2. The pawn can only move 1 step each move.
3. The pawn can not move to a tile if the other pawn is there, or if the tile is markdown.
4. After each move the player can markdown a tile of the board ( one which does not have a pawn and one which is not markdown already).

Here is my solution:

**Getting the possible moves**

```
    public List<Integer> moves(int f, int c) {
    List<Integer> moves= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int nuevaX,nuevaY;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if (!(i == 1 && j == 1)) {
                nuevaX = f + (i - 1);
                nuevaY = c + (j - 1);
                if (disponible(nuevaX,nuevaY) && !ocupada(nuevaX, nuevaY)) {
                    moves.add(nuevaX);
                    moves.add(nuevaY);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return moves;
```

**Iterating**

```
List<Integer> moves = moves(f, c);
    for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i+=2) { 
        x = moves.get(i);
        y = moves.get(i+1);
        //Do some stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have shown is already very fast.

It performs a constant (doesn't change with the size of the board) and very small number (8) of operations.

You may be able to optimize `disponible()` and `ocupada()` methods, but although you haven't shown those, I suspect they are also simple and therefore already fast.

---

As a style note, I suggest that rather than pushing `x` and `y` into a `List<Integer>`, you instead create a `Move` class (or `record` if you're using Java 15), that has `x` and `y` fields and creating a list of `List<Move>` instead, which will make your code easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of is to not create a new ArrayList each time a player moves, rather store an object that retains the position status (empty, occupied, removed, out-of-bounds) of all 8 possible directions of motion. Then you just update the status attached to the player's position.

There may be a way to use bitwise operators / masking to get this status on one pass since the game is only 48 squares total and technically, the only status we care about (aside from keeping stats etc) is CAN and CANNOT move to.

You could mask the board square bits with a byte (N,E,S,W,NE,NW,SE,SW) to get only the relevant ones.